# Sync vim and a regular text editor

Tags: vim

I usually prefer to write my website's paragraphs in LibreOffice. After finishing, I have to copy and paste the text to vim. I would prefer to keep "connected" this two editors, so what I write in LibreOffice is also in vim.

Is there any way to sync contents?

Solutions using Latex are also welcomed, since it is more hackable..

Comment: 1) what Libreoffice brings you but vim doesn't? so that you have to edit in Libreoffice 2) why you need copy things to vim after finishing editing? what vim gives you now and Libreoffice doesn't?

Comment: well, with Libreoffice I have all my texts together, but I could also have them in a file in vim. Maybe a enough solution for me would be  syncing contents between files in gvim..is that possible?

Comment: If you've got a file open in vim and you edit it in another editor, vim will warn you when you switch back and give you the option of reloading the file. Isn't that good enough for syncing content?

Comment: What OS do you use? On Mac OS X, QuickCursor let's you edit text from one application into another: this textfield or text from a LibreOffice document.

Comment: You can synchronise the content in both editors by using something called a 'file'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `set autoread` in your `.vimrc`. Then open the file both in vim and libreoffice, and vim will automatically reload the file if it detects changes.

BTW, if you are missing automatic line filling in vim, look at the [`formatoptions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table) variable.